# Lenovo Thinkpad R500 having problems resuming

Tags: 11.04, power-management, suspend-resume

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 11.04 from scratch on my Thinkpad R500, leaving the default power management settings.

Yesterday I closed the lid, and this morning when I opened it the laptop resumed correctly.

Today during lunch the laptop went to sleep without me closing the lid, and there was no way to wake it up by typing ESC or moving the mouse or TrackPoint. No disk activity at all. When I briefly pushed the POWER button, the laptop rebooted completely, losing my opened applications.

Is it a known problem with Natty/Lenovo Thinkpad R500/ATI?
Any idea what could fix the problem?

Comment: I also faced similar problem. May be there is a problem with video drivers/screen saver. What I did was I have chosen blank screen for my screen saver and also unchecked the option of "Lock screen when screen saver is active" under System->Preferences->Screensaver....

Comment: I have this problem also (on a Lenovo Thinkpad W500). It seems to be correlated with the screen locking, not the suspend/resume exactly. Oddly, the mouse cursor remains visible and even changes between cursor/hand/pointer depending on where in the screen it is; but windows are not visible.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg: Not anymore. Should I close it? delete it?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul You don't have to do anything, I just closed it for you. Thanks for answering! :)